# Como pegar panels de uma página filha no asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, aspx

Estou tentando pegar os panels de uma página filha no asp.net, mas quando uso page.Controls, só recupera os elementos da master page.

Já tentei usar this, Page.Page, mas sempre o mesmo resultado, os elementos da master page e não da página em questão. Veja o algorítimo que usei

```
public static void mostrarPanels(List<String> panels, Page page)
{
    ControlCollection controls = page.Controls;
    foreach(Control control in controls)
    {
        ControlCollection controls2 = control.Controls;
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(Panel)) {
            control.Visible = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < panels.Count; i++)
            {
                if (control.ID == panels[i])
                    control.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Estarei eu fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Olá! Veja se esta resposta ajuda em alguma coisa: https://stackoverflow.com/a/277654/1377664

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void mostrarPanels(List<String> panels)
{
   NomeClassControls page = (NomeClassControls)Page;
   ControlCollection controls = page.Controls;
   foreach(Control control in controls)
   {
     ControlCollection controls2 = control.Controls;
     if (control.GetType() == typeof(Panel)) {
         control.Visible = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < panels.Count; i++)
        {
            if (control.ID == panels[i])
                control.Visible = true;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Tente isso talvez de certo.

Comment: Obrigado, mas consegui resolver.